# How does Windows 10 route network traffic when using a VPN and local proxy at the same time?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, proxy

If I use a VPN on my computer (I.e. Windscribe) while Windows is configured to use a proxy (Located on my home network), how does the traffic flow? Does the VPN client encrypt your packets, which are then sent to the proxy server and forwarded to the VPN exit node, where they are decrypted? Or do I have this backwards?

Answer (score 0):

The packets will be encrypted on the machine where VPN client is installed on. So, if it is running on your computer, it will be encrypted before getting to Proxy Server.